# Express middleware access to req.params

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to isolate a piece of code that would inspect either `req.params` or `req.body` for a value that is required on every request. What I'm finding is that if I try to access those values before `app.use(app.router)` then the request hasn't been parsed to include those objects. If I try to insert the middleware *after* `app.use(app.router)` then it gets skipped all together.

What can I do to work on these values in one place so that the work is ready to be used by downstream routes and models?

Comment: Have you tried monkey-patching with your middleware so that you can inspect it after the request was handled?

Comment: In a word...no. :-) I'm still working on it, but wanted to get a question out there while I do so.

Comment: I have the same scenario.  I have middleware that is being called before I initialize my routes (`app.use(middleware)`), and it can't get `req.params`., but it can get just about everything else, such as `req.query`, etc.  Why is that?

Answer (score 45):

Just run the middleware inline with each route,

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    next();
};

app.get('/test/:id', middleware, (req, res) => {
    res.send('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 23):

You cannot do what you are trying to do.  https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2088 explains this very clearly.

I have been trying to do what you are trying to do for some time, with no success.  I finally tracked down this issue in github.

Comment: This is by design! Paths/routes are matched only after the middleware execution. If you want in any case, use the technique suggested by @mike-james.

Comment: the issue is deleted from github

Answer (score 4):

Since my original answer won't obtain route parameters from the URL, e.g. `/things/:foo` (although it will get querystring and req.body params), it won't work the way we want.  But another option would be to write a wrapper function that does what you need, and apply it to your route middleware:

```
function checkForParam (fn) {

    return function(req, res, next) {

       if (req.param('foo') != 'bar') {
          return res.send(403, 'No way Jose!');
       }

       fn (req, res, next);

    };

}
```

Then add routes with:

```
app.get('/things/:foo', checkForParam(function(req, res, next) {
  // your middleware code here
});
```

This will run the check and proceed to your custom route middleware only if it passes muster.

Comment: En easier approach would then be to chain the mw and route handler.

`app.get('/things/:foo', checkForParam, function (req, res, next) {...});`

checkForParam would then be a normal mw function, not a function returning a function.

Comment: I use the above approach a lot, but I still haven't found a good way to set a mw function that does have access to parsed req.params AND is executed for all routes, without having to list it in each individual route. But maybe that doesn't even make sense since req.params parsing could depend on the route itself. But it's annoying if you have 50 routes all looking like /users/:user/xxx/yyy/zzz and you want to check the user parameter in all routes. I haven't found a better way than to include it before all the routes and parse req.params manually.

Answer (score 2):

Tried a simple core level workaround to get the URL params in router before proceeding into router

I need to validate the URL param id where it is an project id and to check respective user has access to it or not

And i don't want to use it in all routes as middleware so used `split` function to extract the project id which is in URL params

```
  router.use(apiauthenticated,(req,res,next)=>{
     try {  
          //req.params.projectid  
          let temp_projectid=req.originalUrl.split("/") //Getting all endpoints and params
          let last_element=temp_envid[temp_envid.length-1] //Get last element from array for URL params
          let projectid =last_element.includes("?") ? last_element.split("?")[0] : last_element //Returning URL params with or without query params
          if(projectid === "" ){
             //if it is null throwing error
             throw "Please provide required  projectid";
          }
          //Db validation here with projectid
          next();     
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send(error);
            return null;
        }     
  })
```

`apiauthenticated` is the middleware to validate the API Key

Used `last_element.includes("?") ? last_element.split("?")[0] : last_element` for handling the query params

Answer (score 1):

I like this way:

```
const controller = function (name, method) {
  return function (req, res) {
    // COERCE ID
    if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'DELETE') {
      var _id = req.params && req.params._id || false
      if (/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/.test(_id)) {
        req.params._id = new ObjectID(_id)
      }
      else if (_id) {
        return res.status(404).send('Page not found.')
      }
    }
    require('./api/' + name + '.js')[method](req, res)
  }
}
```

Then:

```
app.get('/api/post/:_id', controller('posts', 'get'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I ran into the same issue and managed to resolve this by doing the following.

Let's say I have a system where I would want to have a route that contains the name of a company e.g. `:/company` and I would want to have some middleware extracting the company from the route and add it to every route that matches this structure.

Please note that my examples are in typescript but you should be able to convert them to plain javascript if needed.

```
// company.middleware.ts

/** Helper function if string value exists and is not empty: */
export const isNonEmptyString = (subject: unknown): subject is string =>
  subject !== null &&
  subject !== undefined &&
  typeof subject === "string" &&
  subject.length > 0;

/** a type to cast the request to a request with an optional company property: */
export type IntermediateRequestWithCompany = Request & { company?: string };

/** a type to cast the request to a request with a required company property: */
export type RequestWithCompany = Required<IntermediateRequestWithCompany>;

/** Helper to cast the request to a RequestWithCompany and return the value of company: */
export const getRequestCompany = (req: Request) =>
  (req as unknown as RequestWithCompany).company;

/** Our middleware that will extract the company from params with a default value: */
export const companyMiddleware: NextHandleFunction = (req, res, next) => {
  const intermediate = req as IntermediateRequestWithCompany;
  let company = "default";
  
  if (isNonEmptyString(intermediate.params.company)) {
    company = intermediate.params.company;
  }

  intermediate.company = company;

  next();
};
```

And now for the part where it will start to work: Express has a special method `all`: See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html for more info.

Combining it with my previous code, you can use it like this:

```
// index.ts


/** some basic setup... */
import express from "express";
import {
  companyMiddleware,
  getRequestCompany,
} from "./features/company/company.middleware";

const port = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

/** Here is our hero piece of code: */
app.all("/:company", companyMiddleware);
app.all("/:company/*", companyMiddleware);

/** Let's put it to action here: */
app.get("/:company", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello, ${getRequestCompany(req)}`);
});
app.get("/:company/bye", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Goodbye, ${getRequestCompany(req)}`);
});

/** Code to start the server: */
const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

startServer();
```

That's it, you can test it now by navigating to /Company and /Company/bye which should give you:
`Hello, Company` and `Goodbye, Company`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is one question left : Are you using Express **v. 3 or 4** ???

This is very important here because the concept in v. 4 is different (aka better).

e.g.
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

> app.use(app.router); // <--- this line will be removed

Answer (score -1):

Rather than attempting to do this via custom middleware, you could simply add a wildcard route that will always run before your other routes, and check for the param in there:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {

   if (req.param('foo')) {
      // Do something
      return next(); // or return res.send(403, 'no way!'), or whatever.
   } 

   return next();

});
```

Comment: How will he get the params if they aren't defined yet?

Comment: @Brad: If I read the source correctly, `req.params` is parsed by the router so they'd be available by the time I hit the initial route.

Comment: If that works, just use `app.get('/*', yourMiddleware)`, yeah?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. Have to do the same for all verbs. Maybe express has a shortcut for that...

Comment: Brad, I think I understand your concern now and you're right. There are no defined params in `/*` so `app.all('*' ...)` doesn't do me as much good as it seems like it should.

Comment: Fixed a typo (`params` to `param`), but the params should definitely be in there, and `app.all('/*')` should work just fine.  Just tested myself a moment ago...

Comment: Odd. That didn't work for me. What I found was that if I hit a URL for, say, `/things/:which_one`, then `params.which_one` didn't exist. Instead, the `params` value was `[/things/2029309]` (basically the script_name). Not until I got to my actual route code did it exist as an object.

Comment: Ahh, *now* I see what you're getting at.  You're right; the actual route parameters won't be present yet, since the route hasn't matched.  Only querystring and req.body params are present.  So, one option would be to basically emulate the router in your wildcard middleware.  But, I have a better idea that I will post shortly...