# ExpressJS Middleware | req.params not available in middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

This is ebayApi.handleParams :

```
handleParams : (req, res, next) => {
    for(var param in req.params){
        for(var key in ebayApi.request){
            param == key ? ebayApi.request[key] = req.params[param] : key = key
        }
    }
    next();
},
```

When I do

```
app.use(ebayApi.handleParams);
```

The middleware gets executed, but req.params doesn't have the same value whenever it's inside

```
app.get( '/search', (req, res) => {

});
```

So I'm forced to use middleware like this

```
app.get( '/search', ebayApi.handleParams, (req, res) => {

});
```

Is there a way to fix it? I want to get rid of all the extra typing whenever I create a new route.. It's a middleware that needs to be applied to all incoming requests..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express middleware access to req.params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463299/express-middleware-access-to-req-params)

Comment: I'm going to guess that you actually want to be using `req.query` instead of `req.params`. Also, your code doesn't look very resilient to concurrent usage, because it looks like `ebayApi.request` isn't tied to a specific request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone still interested in the solution?

What I did was create an array of each route that has to go trough the middleware, and then loop trough the array and apply it this way, instead of hard coding it for every route.

```
var routes = [ '/profile/:UserID', '/categories/:CategoryID', '/item/:itemId', '/search/:keywords/:filter*?', '/keywords/:keywords']
for(var route in routes){
    app.all(routes[route], middleware.ebay.handleParams);
}
```

Comment: kudos for not forgetting to post the solution

Answer (score -1):

> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name.

see: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params

your route doesn't have any named parameters